# cellForRowAtIndexPath sees cell as different height when its loaded, then reloaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

Preface: this is quite an abstract question.

I've got some cells in a `UITableView` that use a different image depending on the height of the cell (in 50px increments, from 50px up to 1000px high). I'm hitting a weird issue where when the app first loads, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` reports that the first three cells (regardless of whether or not all three are onscree) have a height of 100px, then when I scroll down and back up again, their height reverts to the correct value. There's no onscreen change of height, only the image used changes, and the value of `cell.frame.size.height` in my `NSLog` statements.

I've been logging in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and I can verify that the heights are correct when they leave `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. But, when entering `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, those first three heights are all set uniformly to 100. I then scroll down until those three cells are off-screen, then scroll back up, and the `.height` value has changed to the correct value.

To summarise, my questions are:

**Is there any code called between the very end of `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and the very beginning of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that could be changing the `cell.frame.size.height` value of these first few cells?**

**Why would this issue only be occurring on the first THREE cells? And, why would they revert when reloaded a moment later? I thought the reuse identifier could be the cause, but they're still assigned that identifier when first loaded, so that shouldn't matter, should it?**

**EDIT:** I think the 100px height is coming from the row height of the prototype cell in my storyboard, as if I change that to 101px, those first three cells are then initially at 101px.

**EDIT:** Here's the code I'm using to set the image, though this part is working, it's just got the wrong value to work with:

```
UIImage *cappedBG;
float cellHeight = cell.contentView.frame.size.height;

if (cellHeight <= 51) {
    cappedBG = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"bg50.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(25, 25, 25, 25) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeStretch];
} else if (cellHeight <= 101) {
    cappedBG = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"bg100.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(25, 25, 25, 25) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeStretch];
} else if (cellHeight <= 151) {
    cappedBG = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"bg150.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(25, 25, 25, 25) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeStretch];
} else if (cellHeight <= 201) {
    cappedBG = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"bg200.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(25, 25, 25, 25) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeStretch];
} else {
    cappedBG = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"bg250.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(25, 25, 25, 25) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeStretch];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just can't rely on the frame of the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. The frame of the cell you configure in that method will be set after the code has returned from this method.

The values you get are not the actual heights of that particular row. You get the height from the cell that has just been dequeued. If there is no cell to dequeue the height from the cell that was just created is used. And 100 is probably the height of the cell in your storyboard/nib.
This height has nothing to do with the height of the cell that will be displayed.

Since you calculate the row height in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` already, use this value.

```
float cellHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cellHeight <= 51) {
    cappedBG = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"bg50.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(25, 25, 25, 25) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeStretch];
...
```

Comment: Looks like that got it. Gimme a few moments to test and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be doing layout of a cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

The best way to do this is to create a UITableViewCell subclass with all the UI elements you need.

Then in the subclass you can override `- (void)layoutSubviews`.

This way you keep everything separate rather than putting EVERYTHING in the view controller.

Comment: I already have a custom cell in place, but I'm interfacing with `CoreData` and an `NSFetchedResultsController` so it's really messy to send data into a custom cell subclass from there for laying it out. If I'm allocating the cell in there, surely any methods I call in a subclass would still be called every time I scroll the table, etc.?

I thought `cellForRowAtIndexPath` was the place Apple recommended you populate a cell. Still fairly new at this.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, after looking at your question, I think you are having trouble with different cell heights (when scrolled). I believe you have not given correct values in heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Following is the simple code that I have written. This code has displays 20 rows in the table and alternate row has different size.(I have used different colours to distinguish)

```
#pragma mark - TableView DataSource Methods

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row %2 == 0) return 50;
    else return 100;
}

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *stringCellIdentifier = @"BookOutVehicleCell";

    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:stringCellIdentifier];

    if (tableViewCell == nil)
        tableViewCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:stringCellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if(indexPath.row %2 == 0) tableViewCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    else  tableViewCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

       return tableViewCell;

}

#pragma mark - TableView Delegate Methods
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

This is the output.

[image]

In this case, even if we scroll the tableview up and down, rows height does not change.

Hope this helps. And sorry If I have misunderstood your question. It would be nice if you provide a code snippet. It will give us better idea about the issue.

**EDIT:**
As per my understanding of the issue you are getting correct heights for each row/cell, however you have used an imageview in cell which will display different images as per the height of the cell. Check if following works for you:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *stringCellIdentifier = @"BookOutVehicleCell";

        UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:stringCellIdentifier];

        if (tableViewCell == nil)
            tableViewCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:stringCellIdentifier] autorelease];

       //Check your height here and use appropriate image 
       if(cell.contentView.frame.size.height <100)
       {
            image = "xxx.png";
       }
       else
       if(cell.contentView.frame.size.height >=100 && cell.contentView.frame.size.height <200)
       {
           image = "yyy.png";
       }


    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: The heights are being set properly in the app, as in the text isn't overlapping onto the next cell, etc. It's drawn correctly, but the height value is incorrect. I'm not even sure how that's possible!

Comment: What do you mean by this **"It's drawn correctly, but the height value is incorrect."**? It would be helpful to understand the issue, if you provide a code snippet.

Comment: I'm saying that the graphic onscreen is correct, but the wrong height image has been used. The cell height is determined based on the text inside it, then a correct image is selected depending on that height. The height looks right in the sim or on device, but it reported as something less than what I can see. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I was already using code very similar to this. I've revised the if statement to use `contentView` as you recommended but it hasn't made any difference, I'm afraid :(

Comment: Could you show me the cellForRowAtIndexPath method? That will help me understand and find out the issue.

Comment: It's a very large method as there are a lot of other decisions being made in there, but I've edited to show the part which assigns the image.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26529/discussion-between-kunal-and-lukech)

Comment: Have you written following method? (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: IF yes you can use float cellHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRoAtIndexPath:index]; to get the exact value. Hope this helps

Comment: The other answer got it right about a second before you did, but I really appreciate the continued help :)